# Why does this reverseArrayInPlace function not work?

Tags: javascript

I have seen answers to this question posted on this website and others, but I am not looking for an answer to the question with another set of code - I am trying to understand why this particular code doesn't work as intended. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The task is to create a function that reverses an array's order in place. The limitations to this task are that I can not use the built in reverse array method and I can not create a second array and just copy over the original. I thought this code would work but it doesn't and I can not figure out why. Thanks in advance.

```
var reverseArrayInPlace = function(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
    var placeHolder = array[i];
    array [i] = array[length - i - 1];
    array[length - i - 1] = placeHolder;
  }
};
```

Comment: Cause `length` is not declared. Just declare it and it will work

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP should listen to its console before asking a question...

Comment: @Jabuzzle What is `length`?

Comment: @JonasW.: Well, declare and *initialize* it.  Probably simplest change is to add as the first line of function: `var length = array.length`.

Comment: Thanks all, much appreciated. I understand now. @Jonas W. when I attempted this code the console returned    [undefined, undefined, 3, 4, 5]   when trying to reverse the array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Either way - sorry if it was a dumb question - I am new - but I am glad I asked because now I understand.

Comment: @jabuzzle no it wasnt dumb, and im glad to help. Its just not useful to other readers, thats why i voted to close. But you should definetly use an IDE that is able to spot such errors. It safes much time and nerves

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you need to either define `length` or use `array.length`.

```js
var reverseArrayInPlace = function(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
    var length = array.length;
    var placeHolder = array[i];
    array [i] = array[length - i - 1];
    array[length - i - 1] = placeHolder;
  }
};

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

reverseArrayInPlace(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I understand it now thanks to all of you!